# approval process assign to user queue

Tags: approval-process, queue

I am creating an approval process(standard setup wizard).

The issue is in the step 3 of, "Specify Approver Field and Record Editability Properties".I want to assign the process to a user queue but I don't see any option of queues there.[image]

Then I followed one of the answers on [Why Can't I Assign an Approval Step to a Queue for a Custom Object Approval Process?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/why-cant-i-assign-an-approval-step-to-a-queue-for-a-custom-object-approval-proc)

But It didn't work. I am creating approval on detail object of a master detail and the queue is made on the master object. But still I'm unable to assign it to user queue.

I see it in a Jump start wizard but not in standard?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign "Next Automated Approver" to the user lookup fields only.

For example, you can assign it to a Standard user Lookup field "Manager" or you can assign it to custom user lookup fields which you have created.

> Approval requests are assigned to an approver from the specified
>   field. You can select only a hierarchical relationship field, such as
>   Manager.

More info on the Next Automated Approver Assignment can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_create_automatedfield.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Ya but how can i assign to the queue's?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't assign it to the queue